# If $U,H$ are Hilbert spaces, $Q$ is an operator on $U$ and $U_0:=Q^{\frac 12}U$, find an expression for the norm of Hilbert-Schmidt operators $U_0→H$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let

- $U$ and $H$ be Hilbert spaces
- $Q$ be a bounded, linear, nonnegative and symmetric operator on $U$
- $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an orthonormal basis of $U$ with $$Qe_n=\lambda_ne_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N$$ for some $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq(0,\infty)$
- $U_0:=Q^{1/2}(U)$ be equipped with $$\langle u_0,v_0\rangle_0:=\langle Q^{-\frac 12}u_0,Q^{-\frac 12}v_0\rangle_U\;\;\;\text{for }u_0,v_0\in U_0$$ where $Q^{1/2}$ is the uniquely determined bounded, linear, nonnegative and symmetric operator on $U$ with $Q^{1/2}Q^{1/2}=Q$ and $$Q^{-1}:=\left(\left.Q\right|_{\left(\ker Q\right)^\perp}\right)^{-1}:Q(U)\to\left(\ker Q\right)^\perp$$ is the pseudoinverse of $Q$

> Let $\text{HS}(U_0,H)$ be the space of Hilbert-Schmidt operators from $U_0$ to $H$. How can we show that $$\left\|L\right\|_{\text{HS}(U_0,H)}=\left\|LQ^{\frac 12}\right\|_{\text{HS}(U,H)}$$ for all $L\in\text{HS}(U_0,H)$?

Note that $$\tilde e_n:=\sqrt{\lambda_n}e_n\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N$$ is an orthonormal basis of $U_0$. Thus,

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left\|L\right\|_{\text{HS}(U_0,H)}^2&\stackrel{\text{def}}=
\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\|L\tilde e_n\right\|_H^2\\
&\stackrel{(\ast)}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\left|\langle L\tilde e_n,x_k\rangle_H\right|^2\\
&\stackrel{\text{def}}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\lambda_n\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\left|\langle Le_n,x_k\rangle_H\right|^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}

for any orthonormal basis $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ of $H$, where I've used Parseval's identity in $(\ast)$.

> Unfortunately, I've no idea how I need to proceed. So, what do we need to do to finish the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a linear bijection
$$
              Q^{1/2} : U \rightarrow U_0
$$
$Q^{1/2}$ is an isometric isomorphism because, by definition, $Q^{1/2}$ is surjective, and is injective because $\lambda_n > 0$ for all $n$, and
$$
          \|Q^{1/2}y\|_{U_0}=\|Q^{-1/2}Q^{1/2}y\|_{U}=\|y\|_{U}.
$$
That also implies that $\{ f_n=Q^{1/2}e_n \}$ is an orthonormal basis of $U_0$.

A linear operator $L : U_0 \rightarrow H$ is of Hilbert-Schmidt class iff
$$
       \sum_{n} \|Lf_n\|_{H}^2 = \sum_{n} \|LQ^{1/2}e_n\|^2_{H}< \infty, \\
          \|L\|^2_{HS(U_0,H)} = \|LQ^{1/2}\|^2_{HS(U,H)} < \infty.
$$

Comment: It should be $\sum_n\left\|Lf_n\right\|_{\color{red}{H}}^2$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d : Thank you. I fixed that now.

Comment: I became confused by a book which presented the equation chain in the question and put the desired expression $\left\|LQ^{\frac 12}\right\|_{\text{HS}(U,H)}$ right after $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\lambda_n\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\left|\langle Le_n,x_k\rangle_H\right|^2$. So, I thought the expression would trivially follow from the previous one. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @0xbadf00d : You're welcome.